# How can I do to add hours and minutes to a time using Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I am trying using Robot Framework from this code to add 3 hours and 5 minutes to the current time :

```
${TESTTIME}  Get Current Date  result_format=%H:%M:%S
${TEMP_TIME}  Add Time To Time  ${TESTTIME}  03 hours 05 minutes  result_format=%H:%M
```

The first line is ok but I got the following error when I launch my test :

```
ValueError: Unknown format '%H:%M'.
```

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

I was expecting to see the current time with more 3 hours and 5 minutes.

Comment: Shouldn't it read just `result_format=hh:mm` as per [this doc](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html#Time%20 formats)?

Answer (score 1):

In the DateTime terminology `time` refers to a timespan like one minute, not to a certain time of a day. That means that `Add Time To Time` isn't a correct keyword to use in this case. You should preserve the full date, add a timespan to it, and format the result:

```
${date}=    Get Current Date
${time}=    Add Time To Date    ${date}    3 hours 5 minutes    result_format=%H:%M
```

If this is all you need to do, a simpler approach is using `increment` with `Get Current Date`:

```
${time}=    Get Current Date    increment=3 hours 5 minutes    result_format=%H:%M
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only confirm your problem. I did not find a conversion similar of what you want.

Below is an example.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           DateTime

*** Test Cases ***
Add time
    ${TESTTIME}=    Get Current Date    result_format=%H:%M:%S
    ${TEMP_TIME}=    Add Time To Time    ${TESTTIME}    03 hours 05 minutes    result_format=timer    exclude_millis=true    # result_format="%H:%M:%S"
    # static calc
    ${TESTTIME}=    Set Variable    22:22:22
    ${TEMP_TIME}=    Add Time To Time    ${TESTTIME}    03 hours 05 minutes    result_format=timer    exclude_millis=true
    # results in ${TEMP_TIME} = 25:27:22
    # With conversion
    ${CONVERTED}=    Convert Time    ${TEMP_TIME}    verbose
    # ${CONVERTED} = 1 day 1 hour 27 minutes 22 seconds
```